# Using 'this' in require'd file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have written a node.js package for personal use in another project. I have been installing it from GitHub link. It was working great, but everything was in a single file which was fine, but now I need to add new functionality to it, thus I thought it'd be a good idea to split it into more than one file.

Thus I created few files to make it work, but let me explain it using just two files `index.js` and `utils.js`.

**Approach 1:**

```
//index.js
const utils = require('./utils.js');
module.exports = {
  indexProperty1:{},
  indexProperty2:[],
  indexFunction1:function(){
    utils.utilsFunction1();
    //some other code
  },
  indexFunction2:function(){
    utils.utilsFunction2();
    //some other code
  }
}

//utils.js
module.exports = {
  utilsProperty1:{},
  utilsProperty2:[],
  utilsFunction1:function(){
    console.log(this); //Prints values of index object
    this.utilsFunction2(); //TypeError: this.utilsFunction2 is not a function
  },
  utilsFunction2:function(){}
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
//index.js
const utils = require('./utils.js');
var index = {};
index.indexProperty1 = {}
index.indexProperty2 = []
index.indexFunction1 = function(){
  utils.utilsFunction1();
  //some other code
}
index.indexFunction2 = function(){
  utils.utilsFunction2();
  //some other code
}
module.exports = index;

//utils.js
var utils = {};
utils.utilsProperty1 = {}
utils.utilsProperty2 = []
utils.utilsFunction1 = function(){
  console.log(this); //Prints values of index object
  this.utilsFunction2(); //TypeError: this.utilsFunction2 is not a function
}
utils.utilsFunction2: = function(){}
module.exports = utils;
```

In both the cases, the value of `this` is the `index` object. Thus calling `this.utilsFunction2()` from `utils` object's any method gives `TypeError`.

So my question is how do you define the `utils` object so that I can use `this` in it and why does this in `utils` object refers to `index` object?

Secondary question: Is there any advantage of using one approach over another in the above example?

Comment: I tried to recreate your scenario using 2 files `index.js` and `utils.js` and it seems to work for me. I am getting the utils object only as the `this` object in `utilsFunction2()` . To answer your other question the two approaches are the same only and i don't think one has any advantage over the other. The only difference is that in the former you are creating a named object and exporting it rather than exporting it directly.

Comment: What is this syntax: `utils.utilsProperty1:{}` and `utils.utilsProperty2:[]`?  That's not regular Javascript that I'm familiar with unless it's inside an object declaration which it is not in your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wanted to initialize those properties with an empty object and an empty array respectively.

Comment: Then, you have to assign to them like this: `utils.utilsProperty1 = {};`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that is an example, there are so many issues wrong with it. The first is you have to have commas between the different `modules.exports` values, second why do you have exports inside of what I assume to be your main (`index.js`)?

Here is some example code that works, not sure if it is exactly what you want, but your question is confusing:

utils.js

```
module.exports = {
  utilsFunction1:function(){
    this.utilsFunction2(); 
  },
  utilsFunction2:function(){
    console.log("success");
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const utils = require('./utils.js');

utils.utilsFunction1();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Node & ES6, I suggest you use Class and Extends

//utils.js

```
class utils {
  utilsFunction1() {
    this.utilsFunction2(); 
  },
  utilsFunction2() {
    console.log("success");
  }
}

module.exports = utils;
```

//index.js

```
var utils = new(require('./utils.js'));
class index {
  indexFunction1() {
    utils.utilsFunction1();
    //some other code
  }
  indexFunction2() {
    utils.utilsFunction2();
    //some other code
  }
}
```

Or: **use extends class: index extends utils**

Hope it help you.

Thanks.